# Java - Extract relevant strings/chars from specific index in file

Tags: java, string, position, chars

I want to extract relevant strings/chars from specific indexe in a txt file. I know how to read the text file line by line but i need help with extracting relevant strings from fixed positions of the line.

lets say i have a txt file that has this content: "1234567891234567892Hello testingblabla"

***I want to extract strings/chars according to this structure:***

**position 0-18**:  123456789123456789

***position 19-20***: 2

***position 20-40***: Hellotestingblabla

I want this to be automated so that the next line gets extracted the same way as the first line that and so on. The values at those indexes will be different but the position will always be the same no matter what.

**What's the best way to tackle these kind of problems? Any classes that are more useful than others?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean. Like this?

```
String str="1234567891234567892Hello testingblabla";
String str1=str.substring(0,18);
String str2=str.substring(18,19);
String str3=str.substring(20,40);
```

Comment: Second value should be length. So (0,18), (18,2) and (20,21)

Comment: Thats one solution i guess, but iam trying to find a good and clean solution because in case I get like 100x lines with different information I want a more general solution to solve these kind of problems.

Comment: Like in a while-loop and store in ArrayLists?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If you want 3 different lists ArrayList <String> value1=new ArrayList<String> ;

Comment: you mean a list for each position? for example pos 0-18 is 1 list, pos 19-20 is 1 list etc.?

Comment: Yes 3 lists. And a method that add the 3 strings to the 3 lists

Comment: is it possible to use switch case for this?
for example: 

switch(someString) 

case someString.subString(0.18):
          do something;

Comment: Case is for a condition. I would make a method with the textline that make the 3 substrings and place them in some kind of list.